# Working remotely over VPN with Win10 and Windows Server (AD, SMB)?

Tags: windows-10, networking, vpn, active-directory, windows-server-2016

We have a small accounting office (5-7 staff members) in which each staff member has a Win10 PC that connects to a local Windows Server 16 system over LAN.  The server handles Active Directory, DNS (for the machines on the AD) and SMB.  Various applications are run locally on the PCs, with all data stored on the server.  Due to COVID-19, we've been all working from home, by using various remote desktop systems to access our office machines from home.  For various reasons, this is proving suboptimal at this point.

What I'd like to do is for each staff member to take their office PC home, and then use VPN (or something similair) to connect to the server.  What I'm envisioning is the some sort of tunnel over VPN so that the server, and the PCs, "think" that they are still on a single LAN, andeach user's applications are still running locally on their PC while the data is still stored on the server.

Is this possible?  If so, what's needed to make it happen?  I've been googling for this, but seem to be missing the right keywords, as I've not found anything relevant to the topic - most of the things I'm finding have to do with using VPN to open a remote desktop connection to the server, a la Windows Terminal Server, which is not what I'm looking for.

I understand that this may require a router that supports VPN.  I believe the one we currently have at the office (SonicWall) does, or we can upgrade it, but I'd definitely prefer it if each of the staff members didn't have to set up a different router at their homes, as not all of them are technically savvy.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is quite do-able and likely within your reach. I am speaking from experience.

Your Sonic Wall very likely offers VPN via the Net Extender Client. This can be set up to access your server.

The client app needs to be installed on the person(s) computers and, yes, they need to take the computers home. Hopefully some are laptops already.

Applications that are chatty databases will not run well over VPN as they are not (likely) client server for remote access. Quick Books is an example.

If you have many apps like this, you will need a terminal server (which you likely do not have).

What I have laid out is workable but not within the range of a non-technical professional to set up.

I suggest you take the above to a local technical consultant who can set this up for you.

Comment: Excellent point +1 for that...  I added a few additional concerns as a separate answer (would be too much for comments).

Answer (score 1):

Setting up a VPN Server is not a big deal, you won't need specialized Hardware on either end of the connection (using e.g. L2TP over IPsec is natively supported by Windows). If your current HW (router/firewall appliance) supports establishing VPN connections even better.

My main concern would be to funnel all the traffic that is going on between the clients and the server on your LAN through the the internet connection (on both sides office and employee's homes). My second concern would be the performance of your router/firewall/server can handle all the traffic resource wise (en/decryption, intrusion detection, etc. all take up CPU and RAM).

I would suggest you know your requirements first, then check if this will work with your current internet connection and HW you are using in the office, also consider the internet connections the employees use.

This all tights in with two excellent points John makes: some clients-server application might require a LAN connection and will just not work over the internet (unless you have fibre etc.). Get a professional on board how can help you with the planing and/or the setup. I'll second both.